# How can I check if sets in a list are subsets of each other?

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list which holds quite a lot of sets and I want to check if there are any subsets of those sets in the list testing each set against one another.

Right now I am doing this like so:

```py
for set1 in list_of_sets:
    for set2 in list_of_sets:
        if set1 < set2:
            <do stuff>
```

Although I am a bit new to python, I have in my urine that this iterating method is a quite un-pythonic way. How can I improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `issubset` method.

```
t = {1,2,3}
s = {1,2}
s.issubset(t)  # True
```

Which is the same as `s <= t`

```py
for set1 in list_of_sets:
    for set2 in list_of_sets:
```

Can be flattened with `product` from the `itertools` module.

```py
from itertools import product

for set1, set2 in product(list_1, list_1):
    ...
```

Or perhaps even better, using `combinations`

```py
from itertools import combinations

for (set1, set2) in combinations(list_of_sets, 2):
    ...
```

There's also perhaps optimization to be had in the approach, but as far as Python-specifics, I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this misses the point. I know about all the `<=`'s and `<`'s and stuff for `set`s. The question is how I can improve the iterating through the list?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind "pythonic". With this code, you'll be testing every pair of sets twice... and also testing each set against itself. Here is one case where it pays to use indices, and save yourself half the computation. But you can still wear the pythonic look and use iteration instead of incrementing an int:

```
for i, set1 in enumerate(list_of_sets):
    for set2 in list_of_sets[i+1:]:
        if set1 < set2:
           do stuff
```

If your collection is *really* large you could do other optimizations like building a partial order (because if `set1 < set2` and `set2 < set3`, you can predict what `set1 < set3` will do), but honestly i doubt it would be worth your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *itertools.permutations* to avoid redundant comparisons with itself combinations

```
for set1, set2 in itertools.permutations(list_of_sets, 2):
    if set1 < set2:
        <do something>
```